# Clicking stop button in my game does not stop the game as expected

Tags: javascript

When the game is over, it pops up with button to play again and if you click that button it will redirect you to play button.

If you click play the game should start but the issue when the game is over and it pop up with first box that has play again button and I click it, the game will redirect me to play button and before i click play button the game will start even i didn't click play button.

I called function eggStop() in PLAY_Again button to stop the game but the game didn't stop. and I call the same function at gameOver() function and it worked only in gameOver().

if there is a recommendation about writing code to enhance it, it will be appreciated.

here is images files
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1vfvcxs7LHg83SLu6L2iGp5zzMWk5zbwV?usp=sharing

```js
var egg1 = document.getElementById("egg1");
var egg2 = document.getElementById("egg2");
var egg3 = document.getElementById("egg3");
var pos1 = 0;
var pos2 = 0;
var pos3 = 0;
var basket = document.getElementById("basket");
var Y_Pos = 0;
var X_Pos = 0;
var Score = 0;
var Life = 10;
var SCORE1 = document.getElementById("SCORE");
var LIFE1 = document.getElementById("LIFE");
var speed1 = 0;
var speed2 = 0;
var speed3 = 0;
var PLAY_Div = document.getElementById("PLAY-Div");
var PLAY_Again = document.getElementById("PLAY-again");
var caption_Score = document.getElementById("caption-score");
var Play_Btn = document.getElementById("PLAY-btn");
var Home1 = document.getElementById("Home");
var basketScore = document.getElementById("basket-score");
var basket_div = document.getElementById("basket-div");
var L = ""
var S = ""



document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
  basket_div.style.left = e.clientX;
  Y_Pos = e.clientY;
  X_Pos = e.clientX;
  console.log("X_Pos" + X_Pos);
  console.log("Y_Pos" + Y_Pos);

})


function eggMove() {
  pos1 = pos1 + speed1 + 30;
  egg1.style.top = pos1+"px";
  console.log("Pos1" + pos1);
  pos2 = pos2 + speed2 + 30
  egg2.style.top = pos2;
  pos3 = pos3 + speed3 + 30;
  egg3.style.top = pos3+"px";
  floorCollision();
}

function eggStop() {
  pos1 = 30;
  egg1.style.top = pos1+"px";
  pos2 = 30
  egg2.style.top = pos2+"px";
  pos3 = 30;
  egg3.style.top = pos3+"px";
}


PLAY_Again.addEventListener("click", function() {
  eggStop(); /* it doesn't work , it can't stop the game/eggs*/
  PLAY_Div.style.display = "none";
  Home1.style.display = "block";

  Life = 10;
  speed1 = 0;
  speed2 = 0;
  speed3 = 0;
  Score = 0;
})

Play_Btn.addEventListener("click", function() {

  setInterval(eggMove, 500);
  Home1.style.display = "none";
  Life = 10;
  speed1 = 0;
  speed2 = 0;
  speed3 = 0;
  Score = 0;
})


function gameOver(Life) {
  if (Life <= 0) {
    eggStop();
    PLAY_Div.style.display = "block";
    caption_Score.innerHTML = Score;
    Life = 0;
    LIFE1.innerHTML = L + Life;

  }
}


function floorCollision() {
  gameOver(Life);

  if (pos1 >= 470) {
    if (120 <= X_Pos && X_Pos <= 275) {
      Score++;
      speed1 = speed1 + 10;
      pos1 = 30;
      egg1.style.top = pos1+"px";
      egg1.src = "imagess/Happy_Egg.svg"
      console.log(Score + "Score1");
      basketScore.innerHTML = Score;
    } else {
      egg1.src = "imagess/Broken_Egg.svg";
      setTimeout(function() {
        pos1 = 45;
        egg1.src = "imagess/Happy_Egg.svg"
        egg1.style.top = pos1+"px";
      }, 500)
      Life = Life - 0.5;
    }
  }

  if (pos2 >= 470) {
    if (530 <= X_Pos && X_Pos <= 690) {
      Score++;
      speed2 = speed2 + 10;
      pos2 = 30;
      egg2.style.top = pos2+"px";
      egg2.src = "imagess/Happy_Egg.svg"
      console.log(Score + "Score2");
      basketScore.innerHTML = Score;
    } else {
      egg2.src = "imagess/Broken_Egg.svg";
      setTimeout(function() {
        pos2 = 45;
        egg2.src = "imagess/Happy_Egg.svg"
        egg2.style.top = pos2+"px";
      }, 500)
      Life = Life - 0.5;
    }

  }
  if (pos3 >= 470) {
    if (940 <= X_Pos && X_Pos <= 1100) {
      Score++;
      speed3 = speed3 + 10;
      pos3 = 30;
      egg3.style.top = pos3+"px";
      egg3.src = "imagess/Happy_Egg.svg"
      console.log(Score + "Score3");
      basketScore.innerHTML = Score;
    } else {
      egg3.src = "imagess/Broken_Egg.svg";
      setTimeout(function() {
        pos3 = 45;
        egg3.src = "imagess/Happy_Egg.svg"
        egg3.style.top = pos3+"px";
      }, 500)
      Life = Life - 0.5;
    }
  }
  S = "SCORE "
  SCORE1.innerHTML = S + Score;
  L = "LIFE "
  LIFE1.innerHTML = L + Life;

}
```

```css
body {
  background-image: url(../imagess/Background_Night.svg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#chicken1 {
  /* background-color: greenyellow; */
  width: 10%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 15%;
  z-index: 1;
  animation: henMove 2s infinite;
}

#chicken2 {
  /* background-color: greenyellow; */
  width: 10%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 45%;
  z-index: 2;
  animation: henMove 2s infinite;
}

#chicken3 {
  /* background-color: greenyellow; */
  width: 10%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 75%;
  z-index: 3;
  animation: henMove 2s infinite;
}

#hen1,
#hen2,
#hen3 {
  width: 85%;
}

#egg1,
#egg2,
#egg3 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 35px;
  top: 45px;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 30%;
}

@keyframes henMove {
  0% {
    width: 150px;
  }
  50% {
    width: 160px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 150px;
  }
}

#PLAY-Div {
  width: 40%;
  /* position: absolute; */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  height: 300px;
  top: 30%;
  left: 30%;
  z-index: 100;
  border-radius: 20%;
  display: none;
}

#PLAY-Div h2 {
  font-size: 80px;
}

#PLAY-Div button {
  font-size: 30px;
}

#Home {
  width: 40%;
  /* position: absolute; */
  background-color: rgba(100, 100, 0, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  height: 300px;
  top: 30%;
  left: 30%;
  z-index: 102;
  border-radius: 20%;
  display: block;
}

#Home h2 {
  font-size: 80px;
}

#Home button {
  font-size: 30px;
}

#basket-div {
  position: relative;
  width: 10%;
  height: 10%;
  top: 550px;
  /* background-color: tomato; */
}

#basket {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50px;
}

#basket-div h3 {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  left: 45%;
  bottom: 75%;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

```html
<!-- Home -->
<div id="Home" class="text-center">
  <h2>HAPPY EGGS</h2>
  <button id="PLAY-btn" class="btn btn-danger w-25 my-5">PLAY </button>
</div>



<!-- Play-Again -->
<div id="PLAY-Div" class="text-center">
  <h2>HAPPY EGGS</h2>
  <h2 id="caption-score"></h2>
  <button id="PLAY-again" class="btn btn-danger w-25 my-5">PLAY AGAIN</button>
</div>


<!-- Score And Life -->
<div id="dashboard" class="text-white d-flex justify-content-between mx-5">
  <h2 id="SCORE">SCORE 0</h2>
  <h2 id="LIFE">LIFE 10</h2>
</div>

<!-- Chicken and Egg -->
<!-- <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">   -->
<div id="chicken1">
  <img id="hen1" src="imagess/Happy_hen.svg">
  <img id="egg1" src="imagess/Happy_Egg.svg">
</div>

<div id="chicken2">
  <img id="hen2" src="imagess/Happy_hen.svg">
  <img id="egg2" src="imagess/Happy_Egg.svg">

</div>

<div id="chicken3">
  <img id="hen3" src="imagess/Happy_hen.svg">
  <img id="egg3" src="imagess/Happy_Egg.svg">

</div>
<!-- </div> -->
<div id="basket-div">
  <h3 id="basket-score">0</h3>
  <img id="basket" src="imagess/Basket.svg">
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/2.4.0/cjs/popper.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `top` needs also the unit in the value, a bare number doesn't do anything.

Comment: I made you a snippet and tried to clean your description. There are errors in the console

Comment: thank you for reply, i added egg1.style.top = pos1+"px";  but still the game didn't stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is that you don't stop the interval from running, so it keeps going.

`eggStop` resets the positions, but the move function keeps being called.

To fix this, you'll need to introduce a global variable to track the interval, and cancel it in `eggStop`.

Put this variable with your other global variables.

```
var intervalID = 0;
```

Then in the event handler you add to the `Play_Btn` click:

```
intervalID = setInterval(eggMove, 500);
```

And then in `eggStop` add:

```
clearInterval(intervalID);
```

Comment: thank you , it's working now , i thought setInterval() will be stopped if i didn't call function again. i also have another question , if you can see i'm reducing life-0.5 because if i reduce it Life-- => it will reduce 2 Lifes instead of 1 but i don't know the reason of that.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure. You lose 0.5 life for every egg that hits the floor, making a total of 1.5 for each round. Without the resetting of the interval then `eggMove` is called n times every interval, where n is the number of times the game has been played without a page refresh. That means that each `floorCollision` is called n times, which would mean you'd lose n*0.5 lives per egg. With the solution above, you should see 1.5 lives lost with each floor collision.

Comment: the 1 if condition in floorCollision will lose  2 Lifes for a single egg but i don't know why although i just wrote Life = Life -1;  , i don't know why it's doubled

Comment: i found the issue and solve it , the issue was in setTimeout(function(){
pos1=45; should be outside this function
})